# Pandas reading from csv file and filling missing values for datetime index

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in a csv file which appears as:

```
  DateTime       Temp
10/1/2016 0:00  20.35491156
10/1/2016 1:00  19.75320845
10/1/2016 4:00  17.62411292
10/1/2016 5:00  18.30190001
10/1/2016 6:00  19.37101638
```

I am reading this file into csv file as:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Curve.csv', index_col='DateTime')
newIndex = pd.date_range(np.min(data.index), np.max(data.index),freq='1H')
data.reindex(newIndex)
```

My goal is to backfill the missing hours 2 and 3 with 19.75320845. i.e. every time there is are missing data it should do the backfill.

Comment: `data.resample('1H').pad()` should do just fine. Just make sure that `data.index` is of `pandas datetime` type before resampling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(r'Curve.csv', index_col='DateTime', parse_dates=['DateTime'])
data = data.asfreq('1H', method='ffill')
```

yields

```
                          Temp
DateTime                      
2016-10-01 00:00:00  20.354912
2016-10-01 01:00:00  19.753208
2016-10-01 02:00:00  19.753208
2016-10-01 03:00:00  19.753208
2016-10-01 04:00:00  17.624113
2016-10-01 05:00:00  18.301900
2016-10-01 06:00:00  19.371016
```

`method='ffill'` tells `asfreq` to "forward-fill" missing values using the
last valid (non-NaN) value.